# ionic camera crash android

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

i'm developing an app that should open the `camera` or select a picture from the photo library, the problem is that if i test the app `build with ionic` (so android-debug.apk) there aren't problems but if i test a `signed apk` (i signed the apk with `android studio`) if i want choose an image from the photo library there aren't problems but if i want to open the camera the app closes and return the messagge "The app "app name" was interrupted".
I've this problem only on android, on iOS it works fine.
I've tried to search on google but i haven't found nothing, and three weeks ago i've published a same app with the same functions and the same code and it works.

**THIS IS MY CODE FOR OPENING CAMERA**:

```
function capturePhoto() {
      // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
        /*navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL }); */


        var srcType = Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA;
        var options = setOptions(srcType);
        var func = createNewFileEntry;

        /*if (selection == "camera-thmb") {
            options.targetHeight = 100;
            options.targetWidth = 100;
        }*/

        navigator.camera.getPicture(function cameraSuccess(imageUri) {

            // Do something

        }, function cameraError(error) {
            console.debug("Unable to obtain picture: " + error, "app");

        }, options);

    }
```

How can i solve this problem?

Thank's

Comment: put your code or create fiddle for check what exact problem is.

Comment: ok, now i edit the question @dkc007

Comment: i've edited the question @dkc007

Answer (score 0):

Always try to use Service here .Because you have to use it in different Controllers,

```
.factory('imageCapt', function($q, $cordovaCamera) {
    var image_url = "";
    var _ChoosePhoto = function () {
                  var options = {
                    quality: 75,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
                    allowEdit: true,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    targetWidth: 300,
                    targetHeight: 300,
                    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: false
                };
                    return $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                        image_url = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                        return image_url;
                    }, function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                    });
                }; 
    var _GetImageUrl= function(){
          var options = {
                    quality: 50,
                    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                    sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                    allowEdit: true,
                    encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                    targetWidth: 100,
                    targetHeight: 100,
                    popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                    saveToPhotoAlbum: true
                };

                    return $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                        image_url ="data:image/jpeg;base64,"+ imageData;                 
                    return image_url;
                    }, function (err) {
                        alert(err);
                        // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                    });
      // $ionicLoading.show({content: 'Loading', animation: 'fade-in',showBackdrop: true, maxWidth: 200,showDelay: 0});

    };
    return {
        GetImageUrl : _GetImageUrl,
        ChoosePhoto : _ChoosePhoto,
    };

})
```

Note : If you don't want to use service then use options correctly in your controller like

```
    var options = {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit: true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 100,
                targetHeight: 100,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true
            };
```

Comment: i haven't error in the console when i run the android-debug.apk but when i run the signed apk the app crash and with the signed apk i didn't use the chrome console

Comment: if you use Android 6 you should ask for user permission before access the camera